Loading ".http" test file in Visual Studio. This triggers an error in the VS 2022 Output Box
I am trying to run a test file for my Web APIs using .http files.
However, whenever I attempt to load the file in Visual Studio 2022 in the output box I get the following:
Executing command 'dotnet tool install Microsoft.dotnet-interactive --version 1.0.506904 --configfile NuGet.config'.

It fails with an SSL exception.

Command 'dotnet tool install Microsoft.dotnet-interactive --version 1.0.506904 --configfile NuGet.config' failed with exit code '1':
Unhandled exception: NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.FatalProtocolException: Unable to load the service index for source https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-tools/nuget/v3/index.json.
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.
System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid because of errors in the certificate chain: PartialChain
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.CompleteHandshake(SslAuthenticationOptions sslAuthenticationOptions)
at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.AddHttp11ConnectionAsync(QueueItem queueItem)
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCompletionSourceWithCancellation1.WaitWithCancellationAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Net.Http.AuthenticationHelper.SendWithAuthAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Uri authUri, Boolean async, ICredentials credentials, Boolean preAuthenticate, Boolean isProxyAuth, Boolean doRequestAuth, HttpConnectionPool pool, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at NuGet.Protocol.ServerWarningLogHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at NuGet.Protocol.ProxyAuthenticationHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSourceAuthenticationHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)   at NuGet.Protocol.HttpRetryHandler.<>c__DisplayClass5_1.<<SendAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()   --- End of stack trace from previous location ---   at NuGet.Protocol.TimeoutUtility.StartWithTimeout[T](Func2 getTask, TimeSpan timeout, String timeoutMessage, CancellationToken token)
at NuGet.Protocol.HttpRetryHandler.SendAsync(HttpRetryHandlerRequest request, String source, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetThrottledResponse(Func1 requestFactory, TimeSpan requestTimeout, TimeSpan downloadTimeout, Int32 maxTries, Boolean isRetry, Boolean isLastAttempt, Guid sessionId, ILogger log, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.<>c__DisplayClass15_01.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func2 action, CancellationToken token) at NuGet.Common.ConcurrencyUtilities.ExecuteWithFileLockedAsync[T](String filePath, Func2 action, CancellationToken token)
at NuGet.Protocol.HttpSource.GetAsync[T](HttpSourceCachedRequest request, Func2 processAsync, ILogger log, CancellationToken token) at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3(SourceRepository source, DateTime utcNow, ILogger log, CancellationToken token) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.GetServiceIndexResourceV3(SourceRepository source, DateTime utcNow, ILogger log, CancellationToken token) at NuGet.Protocol.ServiceIndexResourceV3Provider.TryCreate(SourceRepository source, CancellationToken token) at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T](CancellationToken token) at NuGet.Protocol.PackageMetadataResourceV3Provider.TryCreate(SourceRepository source, CancellationToken token) at NuGet.Protocol.Core.Types.SourceRepository.GetResourceAsync[T](CancellationToken token) at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetPackageMetadataAsync(PackageSource source, String packageIdentifier, Boolean includePrerelease, Boolean includeUnlisted, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetPackageMetadataAsync(String packageIdentifier, NuGetVersion packageVersion, IEnumerable1 sources, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean includeUnlisted)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.GetPackageSourceAndVersion(PackageId packageId, NuGetVersion packageVersion, PackageSourceLocation packageSourceLocation, Boolean includePreview, Boolean includeUnlisted, PackageSourceMapping packageSourceMapping)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.NuGetPackageDownloader.NuGetPackageDownloader.DownloadPackageAsync(PackageId packageId, NuGetVersion packageVersion, PackageSourceLocation packageSourceLocation, Boolean includePreview, Boolean includeUnlisted, Nullable1 downloadFolder, PackageSourceMapping packageSourceMapping) at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.ToolPackage.ToolPackageDownloader.DownloadAndExtractPackage(PackageLocation packageLocation, PackageId packageId, INuGetPackageDownloader nugetPackageDownloader, String packagesRootPath, IToolPackageStore toolPackageStore, NuGetVersion packageVersion, PackageSourceLocation packageSourceLocation, Boolean includeUnlisted) at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.ToolPackage.ToolPackageDownloader.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<InstallPackage>b__0() at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.TransactionalAction.Run[T](Func1 action, Action commit, Action rollback)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallLocalInstaller.Install(FilePath manifestFile)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallLocalCommand.InstallNewTool(FilePath manifestFile)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Tools.Tool.Install.ToolInstallLocalCommand.Execute()
at System.CommandLine.Invocation.InvocationPipeline.Invoke(ParseResult parseResult)
at Microsoft.DotNet.Cli.Program.ProcessArgs(String[] args, TimeSpan startupTime, ITelemetry telemetryClient)


As a test, I have attempted to do things like disabling the SSL (dangerous - I know!).

Is there anything else I could do to fix this? Or is there a workaround to run the `.http` tests in a different way?

**TLDR;**

Trying to run `.http` test files for my Web API in Visual Studio 2022 <- main issue to resolve

Getting issues with the microsoft.dotnet-interactive installation.

SSL issues with https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/dotnet-tools/nuget/v3/index.json

Attempt things like disabling SSL in nuget config.


This is usually due to issues with the SSL certificate chain that prevent a secure connection to the NuGet source. You can check the system's date and time, ensure that the network connection is working properly, and confirm that no firewall or network proxy is blocking access to the NuGet source. Then, check your NuGet.config file to ensure that the configured sources are valid.

I encountered this issue in Visual Studio 2022 and figured out that one of my custom Nuget sources, a local directory for my own nuget publishing, was not meeting the security threshold needed. This is just a folder on my machine so this seems like a bug.
To fix the issue, I went into Tools/Options, unchecked that Package Source checkbox, and restarted VS and it worked from there.

